# CMake undefined reference while working on a multiple layer project

Tags: c++, cmake

Im working on a big project which needs a better organized CMake and in my tries I always encounter the undefined reference problem. First of all, I will add an image with how the project is structured:

[Image with a tree image of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk6jt.png)

Each of the domain and subdomain folders have a CMakeLists.txt.

Simplified Structure of root CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(3.18)
project(PROJECT)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Structure of src CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(3.18)

add_subdirectory(domain1)
...
add_subdirectory(domain n)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROEJCT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain1>
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROEJCT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain2>
    ...
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROEJCT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain n>
)

target_link_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}-main
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    ...
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    - some external libraries which work fine
)
```

Structure of a domain CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(3.18)

add_subdirectory(subdomain1)
...
add_subdirectory(subdomain n)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1 OBJECT
    <TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain1>
    <TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain2>
    ...
    <TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain n>
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    ...
)

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1
    ${COMMON_FLAGS}
)
```

Structure of a subdomain CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(3.18)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain1 OBJECT
    source1.cpp
    source2.cpp
    ...
    source_n.cpp
)

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src
    ...
)

target_compile_options(${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1-subdomain1
    ${COMMON_FLAGS}
)
```

Now that I presented the structure, I have a problem with the src CMakeLists.txt, I am trying to remove the add_executable() from it because having each subdomain there is becoming a mess. So far, I've been trying to create for each domain a separate project. In each domain I would link the libraries from the subdomain, but now I don't know where should I have the add_executable() part, because having multiple projects means I cannot do something like:

```
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:${PROJECT_NAME}-domain1>
)
```

My end goal would be to totally remove the add_executable() from src or to have only the domains as target and not each subdomain. Any ideas how could I achieve this?

While trying to make the subproject ideea with each domain and linking the libraries in the src, I've encountered undefined reference for each source file in the domain.

Comment: `have only the domains as target` then remove OBJECT `linking the libraries` there are no libraries, they are only object files. Make them a library, like static. If you want to optimize a project, use LTO.

Comment: Hello, I  tried now removing OBJECT and targeting only the domains and so far it is not working, I get a lot of dwarf error debug str larger than its file size, followed by the undefined reference to the source files.

Comment: One important mention that I didn't see before, I observe that the undefined functions appear when for example: domain1 uses functions from domain2.

Comment: You have to `target_link_libraries(domain1 PUBLIC domain2)` if it uses them.

Comment: I am not really sure where I should add this, I tried adding it once in src and second time in the domain specific CMake and neither of them worked.

Comment: Couldn't you just write `add_executable(MyExe)` and then just add `target_sources(MyExe PRIVATE "source1.cpp" ...)` in subfolders?